# How to Compile Jung Source?

Tags: java, jung, graph-layout

Recently I'd downloaded Jung API from their Website with all library that must be included.
But when I'm trying to compile that,It fails. Can any boy help me,please? (I'm using Netbeans IDE)
Gratefully.

Comment: It will be a lot easier to help you if you tell us what the error you are getting is.

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans you should go to yourProject->Libraries. Then click right mouse button on it, choose "Add JAR/Folder" and select all jung jars (hold shift and use arrow keys). Have you already tried as I say?